# How to implement a web based file manager targeting Azure blob storage with Angular 2 and WEB API

Tags: angular, .net-core, azure-storage, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I want to implement a file manager targeting Azure Blob Storage for any media upload.It should able to create folders,move contents from one folder to another similar to this [demo](https://qjon.github.io/angular2-filemanager/) using Angular 2 as frontend and WEB API at backend.

I have tried [CKFinder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/ckfinder/),[angular-filemanager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rign/angular2-filemanager) but they are not meeting requirements of a structured media center like functionality.

I found one well structured file manager [RichFilemanager](https://github.com/servocoder/RichFilemanager) but it is not supporting Angular 2.

Can anyone help me in implementing this file manager stuff in Angular 2????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend checking the following Module:**https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-azure-blob-service**

> A simple module for communication with Azure Blob Storage from angular apps. Works with @angular 4.3+

At least this would get you started since it's only compatible with 4.3+.

Then if you'd like more info, I'd advise on checking this **[blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/06/29/uploading-images-to-azure-storage-from-angularjs-app/)**
the author used Angular modules already made here: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.I will follow that and try to solve my issue.